# Finding all n digit binary numbers with r adjacent digits as 1

Tags: algorithm, math, binary

Let me explain with an example. If n=4 and r=2 that means all 4 digit binary numbers such that two adjacent digits can be 1. so the answer is 0011 0110 1011 1100 1101

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Probably the question :)

Comment: @leppie I don't see a question, do you?

Comment: This is basically a form of run-length limited (RLL) coding. I believe it's usually done by counting in normal binary, then converting the result to the chosen RLL.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen my question is what could be an algorithm for this? i am unable to figure out a pattern or an algorithm.

Comment: you want to generate them, or just calculate how many?

Comment: @chris I want to generate them.

Comment: you can use backtracking, try it and see if you have problem, ask it.

Comment: I am a bit unclear about the constraint. Are `11011` and `111011` valid outputs for m=2?

Comment: @vhallac no 11011 is but 111011 is not because it has 3 adjacent 1's

Comment: @ritratt Then you will have to do it the hard way in my answer below (the recursive one).

Comment: This question was unreasonably closed. For the record, a question of the same type was posted at stackoverflow.com/questions/12311918/ and answered. I can only guess the answer to this question is 2^n - F_m(n+m), where F_m are the m-step Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q. i am unable to figure out a pattern or an algorithm.

Hint:  The 11 can start in position 0, 1, or 2.  On either side, the digit must be zero, so the only "free" digits are in the remaining position and can cycle through all possible values.

For example, if there are n=10 digits and you're looking for r=3 adjacent ones, the pattern is

```
x01110y
```

Where *x* and *y* can cycle through all possible suffixes and prefixes for the remaining five free digits.  Note, on the sides, the leading and trailing zero gets dropped, leaving six free digits in *x0111* and *1110y*.

Here's an example using Python:

```
from itertools import product

def gen(n, r):
    'Generate all n-length sequences with r fixed adjacent ones'
    result = set()

    fixed = tuple([1] * r + [0])
    for suffix in product([0,1], repeat=n-r-1):
        result.add(fixed + suffix)

    fixed = tuple([0] + [1] * r + [0])
    rem = n - r - 2
    for leadsize in range(1, rem):
        for digits in product([0,1], repeat=rem):
            result.add(digits[:leadsize] + fixed + digits[leadsize:])

    fixed = tuple([0] + [1] * r)
    for prefix in product([0,1], repeat=n-r-1):
        result.add(prefix + fixed)

    return sorted(result)
```

Comment: the cycling through the remaining possibilities is the hard part though. If you permute the leftwards only paddings of the block of 1's, and union with the rightwards only paddings, you'll still miss some. Padding on both sides of a block, I think is tricky to not create duplicates, although I think it's the way to go.

Comment: duplicates are not a problem. I am going to try this logic. thanks!

Comment: This almost works. but gives an invalid output 111011 for n=6 and r=2

Comment: @ritratt Why is 111011 an invalid output?  It has a group of two adjacent ones.  Did you intend to add a constraint that the output should have __at most__ two consecutive ones?

Comment: Yes it should have at most two consecutive ints. I solved the above bug and now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with simplifying the problem. Once you have a solution for the simplest case, generalize it and then try to optimize it.

First design an algorithm that will find out if a given number has 'r' adjacent 1s. Once you have it, the brute-force way is to go through all the numbers with 'n' digits, checking each with the algorithm you just developed.

Now, you can look for optimizing it. For example: if you know whether 'r' is even or odd, you can reduce your set of numbers to look at. The counting 1's algorithm given by KNR is order of number of set bits. Thus, you rule out half of the cases with lesser complexity then actual bit by bit comparison. There might be a better way to reduce this as well.

Comment: I could search the binary number as a string but that's not optimal. I was wondering if there is a mathematical pattern to this.
Also, I m unable to figure out an algorithm for the simplest case except for searching the binary number as a string.

Comment: I need to think more about it. If it was just finding the number of such numbers, it is easy. let's say r is 2 and n is 4. Then 11 will be together somewhere in 4 places. Thus rest two places can have different permutation of digits / values. Thus four such values. If n is say 20, then 20-2, 18 such positions are there, thus 2^18 such numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Funny problem with very simple recursive solution. Delphi.

```
  procedure GenerateNLengthWithROnesTogether(s: string;
    N, R, Len, OnesInRow: Integer; HasPatternAlready: Boolean);
  begin
    if Len = N then
      Output(s)
    else
    begin
      HasPatternAlready := HasPatternAlready or (OnesInRow >= R);
      if HasPatternAlready or (N - Len > R) //there is chance to make pattern}
       then
        GenerateNLengthWithROnesTogether('0' + s, N, R, Len + 1, 0, HasPatternAlready);
      if (not HasPatternAlready) or (OnesInRow < R - 1) //only one pattern allowed
      then
        GenerateNLengthWithROnesTogether('1' + s, N, R, Len + 1, OnesInRow + 1, HasPatternAlready);
    end;
  end;

begin
  GenerateNLengthWithROnesTogether('', 5, 2, 0, 0, False);
end;

program output:
N=5,R=2
11000  01100 11010  00110
10110  11001 01101  00011
10011  01011

N=7, R=3
1110000 0111000 1110100 0011100
1011100 1110010 0111010 1110110
0001110 1001110 0101110 1101110
1110001 0111001 1110101 0011101
1011101 1110011 0111011 0000111
1000111 0100111 1100111 0010111
1010111 0110111
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated in the comment above, I am still unclear about the full restrictions of the output set. However, the algorithm below can be refined to cover your final case.

Before I can describe the algorithm, there is an observation: let *S* be `1` repeated `m` times, and *D* be the set of all possible suffixes we can use to generate valid outputs. So, the bit string `S0D0` (S followed by the 0 bit, followed by the bit string *D* followed by the 0 bit) is a valid output for the algorithm. Also, all strings `ror(S0D0, k)`, `0<=k<=n-m` are valid outputs (`ror` is the *rotate right* function, where bits that disappear on the right side come in from left). These will generate the bit strings `S0D0` to `0D0S`. In addition to these rotations, the solutions `S0D1` and `1D0S` are valid bit strings that can be generated by the pair (*S*, *D*).

So, the algorithm is simply enumerating all valid *D* bit strings, and generating the above set for each (*S*, *D*) pair. If you allow more than `m` 1s together in the *D* part, it is simple bit enumeration. If not, it is a recursive definition, where D is the set of outputs of the same algorithm with `n'=n-(m+2)` and `m' is each of {m, m-1, ..., 1}`.

Of course, this algorithm will generate some duplicates. The cases I can think of are when `ror(S0D0,k)` matches one of the patterns `S0E0`, `S0E1` or `1E0S`. For the first case, you can stop generating more outputs for larger `k` values. `D=E` generator will take care of those. You can also simply drop the other two cases, but you need to continue rotating.

---

I know there is an answer, but I wanted to see the algorithm at work, so I implemented a crude version. It turned out to have more edge cases than I realized. I haven't added duplication check for the two last yields of the `family()` function, which causes duplication for outputs like `11011`, but the majority of them are eliminated.

```
def ror(str, n):
    return str[-n:]+str[:-n]

def family(s, d, r):
    root = s + '0' + d + '0'
    yield root  # root is always a solution
    for i in range(1, len(d)+3):
        sol=ror(root, i)
        if sol[:r]==s and sol[r]=='0' and sol[-1]=='0':
            break
        yield sol
    if d[-r:]!=s: # Make sure output is valid
        yield s + '0' + d + '1'
    if d[:r]!=s:  # Make sure output is valid (todo: duplicate check)
        yield '1' + d + '0' + s

def generate(n, r):
    s="1"*r
    if r==0: # no 1's allowed
        yield '0'*n
    elif n==r: # only one combination
        yield s
    elif n==r+1: # two cases. Cannot use family() for this
        yield s+'0'
        yield '0'+s
    else:
        # generate all sub-problem outputs
        for rr in range(r+1):
            if n-r-2>=rr:
                for d in generate(n-r-2, rr):
                    for sol in family(s, d, r):
                        yield sol
```

You use it either as `[s for s in generate(6,2)]`, or in a loop as

```
for s in generate(6,3):
    print(s)
```