# Number of subsets of {1,2,3,...,N} containing at least 3 consecutive elements

Tags: math, combinatorics

Suppose we have a set like `{1,2,3}` then there is only one way to choose 3 consecutive numbers... it's the set {1,2,3}...

For a set of {1,2,3,4} we have 3 ways: `123` `234` `1234`

(technically these are unordered sets of numbers, but writing them consecutively helps)

- f(5) ; {1,2,3,4,5} -> 8 ways: `123` `1234` `1235` `12345` `234` `2345` `345` `1345`
- f(6) ; {1,2,3,4,5,6} -> 20 ways: ...
- f(7) ; {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} -> 47 ways: ...

So for a given N, I can get the answer by applying brute force, and calculating all such subset having 3 or more consecutive number.

Here I am just trying to find out a pattern, a technique to get the number of all such subset for a given N.

The problem is further generalized to .....discover m consecutive number within a set of size N.

Comment: How are there 20 ways to choose a substring of 12345 of length >=3? I only count 6.

Comment: If it is homework, please tag the question as `homework` and mention what you've tried. Thanks!

Comment: There are more than 6. To list a few: 123 234 345 124 125 235 245 135 1234 2345 1245 1345 12345

Comment: @DrBards 124, 125 and so on aren't consecutive number sequences

Comment: good point.. then I agree, the question is inconsistent

Comment: srry for confusion its 8 for 5 and so on(typo mistkae), I have updated the question

Comment: @ninjagecko Perhaps more:  123, 234, 345, 1234, 1235, 1345, 2345, 12345

Comment: I don't know why (1,2,3,4) counts as 3 consecutive numbers.  Why are your input sets always consecutive themselves?  How can you find 8 ways for 5... I see only 123 234 345 1234 2345 12345: which is 6 (assuming in fact you can choose any length subset > 3).

Comment: @Alex:this is my calculation for 5 the 8's are as...(3,4,5), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,3,4,5), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,5), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,4,5)....u can find more by generating all the 2^5 set and then counting the number of consecutive one there

Comment: Is the set of N numbers consecutive? What if you were to choose these from the set `{1,2,3,5}` and so on? I think you mean "from the set of positive integers <= N"

Comment: @ ninjagecko: if N=4, then the subsect lies within (1...4) and for N=5 (1....5) and the above test case (1,2,3,5)comes in picture for N=5....here my focus is to getting the no. of ways...I have written the above soltuin assuming N==5 (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: @Verde: reverted title change because "with size >=3" is not necessary since if the subsets have size < 3 they will not satisfy "at least 3 consecutive elements", please let me know if you disagree or if you think we should change re-add the change.

Comment: @ninjagecko you are right, but I saw so many misinterpretations that decided to include a little redundancy

Comment: @Verde: good point, I edited the answer to try to make it clearer

Comment: @ninjagecko Hey! it looks great now! Congrats!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bijection between this problem and "the number of N-digit binary numbers with at least three consecutive `1`s in a row somewhere" (the bijection being a number is 0 if excluded in the subset, and 1 if included in the subset).

This is a known problem, and should be enough information to google for a result, if you search for `number of n-digit binary strings with m consecutive 1s`, the second hit is [Finding all n digit binary numbers with r adjacent digits as 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510060/finding-all-n-digit-binary-numbers-with-r-adjacent-digits-as-1)

Alternatively you can just look it up as http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C0%2C1%2C3%2C8%2C20%2C47 (based on the brute-forcing you did for the first few terms) - resulting in an explicit formula of `2^n - tribonacci(n+3)`, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html) for an explicit formula for tribonacci numbers. It also gives a recurrence relation. The analogy given is "probability (out of 2^n) of getting at least 1 run of 3 heads within n flips of a fair coin"

I can only assume that the answer to the general problem is 2^n - F<sub>m</sub>(n+m), where F<sub>m</sub> is the m<sup>th</sup> [n-step Fibonacci number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html) (*edit: that does [seem to be the case](http://oeis.org/search?q=%09+a%28n%29+is+the+number+of+n-tosses+having+a+run+of+or+more+heads+for+a+fair+coin)*)

Comment: hee, I was going to post the same :). The recurrence relation is `a(n) = 3*a(n-1) - a(n-2) - a(n-3) - 2*a(n-4), a(0)=0, a(1)=0, a(2)=1, a(3)=3.`

Comment: Damn ... an answer so nice and remains almost unseen. Unfair world.

Comment: @rspr: well I didn't really explain it, just cited such that you can look up proofs. You can also probably reverse-engineer the solution: tribonacci(n+3) must be the number of n-digit strings with NO run of 3 consecutive elements, for example.

Comment: @ninjagecko: right...actually I was not familiar with the concept of tribonacci()...and here I was missing....Now I can come up with a proof.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework to me, so I'll just get you started. FoOne approach is to think of the Lowest and Highest members of the run, L and H. If the set size is N and your minimum run length is M, then for each possible position P of L, you can work out how many positions of H there are....

Comment: its not a home work ...this is the pattern I have discovered by writing solution to algorithmic problem...and I believe there must be some mathematically proved solution is there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean consecutive or not. If not, then for {1, 2, 3, 4} there are 4 possibilities: {1, 2, 3} {2, 3, 4} {1, 3, 4} {1, 2, 3, 4}

I think you can calculate the solution with N!/3! where N! = N*(N-1)*(N-2)*...*1.

Comment: Hence I said "Not sure if you mean consecutive or not. *If not*, ..." Please read before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of python code, we can investigate this:

```
y = set()

def cons(li, num):
    if len(li) < num:
        return
    if len(li) == num:
        y.add(tuple([i for i in li]))
    else:
        y.add(tuple([i for i in li]))
        cons(li[1:], num)
        cons(li[:-1], num)
```

This solution will be quite slow (it's exponential in complexity, actually), but try it out for a few small list sizes and I think you should be able to pick up the pattern.

Comment: And just to add a comment to my own answer, this of course will generate a different set to what to question -now- asks, and of course will generate the same values as the (far more comprehensive) solution posted by @AlexBrown.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick answer:

```
Sequences(n) = (n-1)*(n-2) / 2
```

### Long answer:

You can do this by induction.  First, I'm going to re-state the problem, because your problem statement isn't clear enough.

- Rule 1: For all sets of consecutive numbers 1..n where n is 2 or more
- Rule 2: Count the subsets S(n) of consecutive numbers m..m+q where q is 2 or more

### S(n=3)

By inspection we find only one - 123

### S(n=4)

By inspection we find 3! - 123 234 and 1234

Note that S(4) contains S(3), plus two new ones... both include the new digit 4... hmm.

### S(n=5)

By inspection we find ... S(n=4) as well as 345 2345 and 12345.  That's 3+3=6 total.

I think there's a pattern forming here.  Let's define a new function T.

- Rule 3: S(n) = S(n-1) + T(n) ... for some T.

We know that S(n) contains the digit n, and should have spotted by now that S(n) also contains (as a subcomponent) all sequences of length 3 to n that include the digit n.  We know they cannot be in S(n-1) so they must be in T(n).

- Rule 4: T(n) contains all sequence ending in n that are of length 3 to n.

### How many sequences are in S(n)?

Let's look back at S(3) S(4) and S(5), and incorporate T(n):

- S(3) = S(3)
- S(4) = S(3) + T(4)
- S(5) = S(4) + T(5) = S(3) + T(4) + T(5)

let's generalise:

- S(n) = S(3) + T(f) for all f from 4 to n.

So how many are in a given T?

Look back at rule 5 - how many sequences does it describe?

For T(4) it describes all sequences 3 and longer ending in 4.  (that's 234)

For T(5) it describes all sequences 3 and longer ending in 5.  (that's 345 2345 = 2)

```
T count Examples
4 2     1234 234
5 3     12345 2345 345
6 4     123456 23456 3456 456
```

Looks awfully like T(n) is simply n-2!

So

```
S(6) = T(6) + T(5) + T(4) + S(3)
  10 = 4    + 3    + 2    + 1
```

And 
    S(7) = 15 = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
    S(8) = 21 = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

### Turning this into a formula

What's 2 * S(8)?

42 = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6

Add each pair of biggest and smallest numbers:

42 = 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7

42 = 7 * 6

But that's 2 * S(8), so

S(8) = 42/2 = 21 = 7 * 6 / 2

This generalizes:

```
S(n) = (n-1)*(n-2) / 2
```

Let's check this works:

```
S(3) = 2*1/2 = 1
S(4) = 3*2/2 = 3
S(5) = 4*3/2 = 6
S(6) = 5*4/2 = 10
```

I'm satisfied.

Comment: Apparently my problem statement is wrong, but then I don't care, I had fun doing it, and next time the OP can clearly state the rules.